# Is there a way to remove allocated pages that are not associated with a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, diskspace

We have an "mdf" file for a database that has grown enough to fill up a 200GB disk on our SQL Server Windows machine. I used the query shown below to list the tables in that database with their "reserved" sizes. The result with the larges size is grouped with table and schema named "NULL".

How can I access and review and eventually remove these allocated pages from the database in order to shrink the "mdf" file's footprint on the disk?

Query (thanks to https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky):

```
use temp_db;
SELECT sch.[name], obj.[name], ISNULL(obj.[type_desc], N'TOTAL:') AS [type_desc],
   COUNT(*) AS [ReservedPages],
   (COUNT(*) * 8) AS [ReservedKB],
   (COUNT(*) * 8) / 1024.0 AS [ReservedMB],
   (COUNT(*) * 8) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 AS [ReservedGB]
FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, DEFAULT) pa
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects obj
    ON obj.[object_id] = pa.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON sch.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((sch.[name], obj.[name], obj.[type_desc]), ())
ORDER BY [ReservedPages] DESC;
```

Results (top 3 rows plus header, with big "ReservedGB" highlighted):

| name | name | type_desc | ReservedPages | ReservedKB | ReservedMB | ReservedGB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | TOTAL: | 15414665 | 123317320 | 120427.070312 | 117.604560851562 |
| data | crm_isc_sales_work_oppor_1b22e | USER_TABLE | 4451592 | 35612736 | 34778.062500 | 33.962951660156 |
| data | pr_data_ih_dim_action | USER_TABLE | 2705708 | 21645664 | 21138.343750 | 20.642913818359 |

I've tried restarting the SQL Server Database Engine (and Agent) as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-ver16

That restart did not free up those allocated pages.

Comment: Are you sure there are any such pages in the first place, and you aren't looking at the grand total? Format your results so people can understand what is shown. Besides, databases *don't* reduce the file size by themselves because it's a bad idea. In most cases, if a table grew to a certain size it will grow *again* after deleting rows. Reducing a file's size will only result in reallocating the same space again. In production databases, DBAs may not even allow automatic growth, preferring to allocate space themselves to reduce fragmentation

Comment: [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#group-by-) ***GROUP BY ()**
Specifies the empty group, which generates the grand total.*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Where did this query come from? I'm not sure what the motivation would be for using the undocumented `sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations` for this rather than the more efficient `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`

Answer (score 1):

For non-table usage, i think Shrink is your friend but it's not without downsides.

In SSMS there's a handy report that displays reserved and actual size of tables. If you right click on the database you're interested in and select Reports -> Standard Reports -> Disk usage by top tables.

If there's a lot of "air" between reserved and taken space, you could rebuild your indexes (especially clustered (by using ALTER INDEX xxx ON yourtable REBUILD) and it will perhaps get some space back.
Restarting server shouldn't make any difference me think.

You could shrink your db as well, but that usually has some problems with defragmentation.

If you have very large tables, something rebuild will take forever / not succeed, in that case you might wanna copy data to some other table and "rebuild" it manually by truncating original and copying it back.
Your mileage may vary.

Comment: The real problem with shrinking the DB on it's own is it fails to address the issue that caused the data to grow in the first place. Very often there's some daily or weekly job to temporarily balloon the data, and not understanding how that runs will result in at best a transient gain.